# python-traitsui. Update property before completion of button fired

Tags: python, user-interface, enthought, traitsui

I am trying to get a property and GUI to update before the end of a button fired action.
I feel like this should be straightforward but I am missing an `update` command or something.

The portion of the code is below:

```
item1 = Property(Str, depends_on = ['button1'])
button1 = Button('Perform Action')

myview = View(Item('button1'), Item('item1'))

def _get_item1(self):
        return somefunction()

def _button1_fired(self):
        dosomething1()
        dosomething2()
```

When the button is pressed, `dosomething1()` will change the output of `somefunction()`. And `dosomething2()` will change the output of `somefunction()` to something else. However when this is run the GUI will only update `item1` after `_button1_fired` is finished.

Is there a way or a command to insert between the two `dosomething()` functions so that the GUI is updated "live"

Comment: Try posting your question here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ets-users

Comment: I ended up solving my issue by using the concept of `threading` (which I was unaware of at the time of my question).